# how to broadcast messages using api.ai bots

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, wit.ai, chatfuel

I'm developing chat bots on Api.ai
I have a case in which i have to broadcast via bot

e.g:

- ask for standup report in morning on slack and Instagram
- when any buddy add a row in excel sheet on Instagram
- when special Occasions and events are coming on Instagram
- notifications on Instagram

Chatfuel have [Broadcast feature](https://help.chatfuel.com/facebook-messenger/broadcasting/) while I didn't found any way to do this job on Api.ai, please let me know how to do this job with Api.ai since Api.ai is the choice of 70% bot developers

Comment: The title of the questions seems not to be related with the question itself...

Comment: ohh yes i just corrected it was from previous draft